# Xpath для HtmlAgilityPack C#

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Есть такое код страницы:

```
<html lang="ru" xml:lang="ru" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<div id="rates_block"><table id="content_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
<td class="info"><img src="./new_files/ajax.gif" id="update_image" class="hide" width="16" height="16"></td><td class="changer"><a href="" title=""</a></td>
</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<tr onclick="">
<td class="ir"><span class="io" id="io0" </span></td>
<td class="bj"><div class="pa labpad1"><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank"</div></td>
<td class="bi"><div class="fs">1 <small>John</small></div><div class="fm"><div class="fm1">Smith</div></div></td>
<td class="bi">Say<small>My Name</small></td>
 </table></div>
```

Подскажите,как составить выражение,чтобы вытащить значение Say из последнего td
Пробовал так,но выдёргивает только первый класс bi

```
string bi = class.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='bi']").InnerText;
```

Comment: Либо использовать `last()` в XPath, либо заменить `SelectSingleNode` на `SelectNodes`(или как то так) и брать последний (`LastOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

Решилось такой строкой:

```
string bi = class.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("(//td[@class='bi'])[2]").InnerText;
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что это плохое решение? Вы прибиваете строго гвоздями ко 2-му элементу. А если их там будет вдруг 10 и вам надо обязательно последний, то что тогда? Парсинг (особенно сайта, который довольно часто меняется) это дело не стабильное и я вам крайне не советую прибивать все гвоздями через выбор элемента по индексу...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ задача состояло в парсе строго второго элемента

Comment: `вытащить значение Say из последнего td ` - где тут сказано, что строго из второго? Вы просите нас с помощью выбора последнего элемента, я вам подсказал как это грамотно сделать. Как вдруг вышло, что нужно 2-ой элемент? Хорошо, если элемент 2-ой вдруг, то по индексу тоже неверно. Вы не ответили что будет, если вдруг сайт поменяет структуру и ваш 2-ой элемент вдруг окажется 10-м, ну или 1-ый.